# C#. what type must be variable

Tags: c#

> what type must be 'fun' if there were no compile errors

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int[] a = { 5, 3, 4 };
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < fun.Length; i++)
                sum = sum + fun[i](a[i]);
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
        }
     }
```

Comment: This is clearly homework. Please try, it's for your learning not just to annoy you.

Comment: This isolated piece of code will not compile.

Comment: `fun` must evaluate to an object, such as an array or List, with an `[](int)` indexer (or less refined) which itself must return a `Func<int,int>` (or equivalent delegate) which takes in an integer (although it could be less refined) and returns an integer (or type that can be implicitly converted to such).

Answer (score -5):

To make it compilable, you may add a local variable `fun` like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Func<int, int>[] fun = new Func<int, int>[0]; // <--
    int[] a = { 5, 3, 4 };
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < fun.Length; i++)
        sum = sum + fun[i](a[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

Comment: @AlexD, don't encourage people to post "simple homewrok" without attempting anything.

Comment: I disagree with the down votes, its a question and answer site. He asked a question and got the answer.

Comment: @Xela Paste your homework and get the answer, do you think this is what SO is for? No, We are not here to do the work for lazy people.

Comment: @EZI Who says he hasn't tried. Whats the difference posting a work problem and posting a school question. You need some reference to learn from.

Comment: @Xela **I say it.**, and the others who voted down. We need a sign of some research and we don't see it.

Comment: @EZI well I say he may have. You sound like a Narcissist.

Comment: @Xela all you can do is this?. Trying to insult?  Good luck in your SO life.

Comment: @EZI no I like to help, you don't.

Comment: @Xela writing the homework/job  for someone who doesn't show any effort to do it is not a help for him. I wouldn't want someone like this be  my college in the near future, would you?

Comment: @EZI Its a QA site = Ask question, get an answer. No where does it say its only for Questions and only Answers if proof of research. Show me in the websites rules or terms and conditions where it lists this.

Comment: @Xela As OP,  you should need some research too (I did it for you) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @EZI it isn't a requirement so someones answer shouldn't be down voted.

Comment: @Xela this link is on the bottom of the page linked by EZI. And this was voted that it should be followed for questions regarding homework. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Also the rules on this site say questions should show research and effort to be a valid question.

Comment: @deathismyfriend your wrong, it is a community based decision that not the whole community follow. Your just trying to force your own ways amongst the community. I will not follow these "community based rules" until they are officially in the sites terms of use. This answer is correct and does not deserve down votes. There is no reasoning behind it except for ignorance of the community. Its like hosting a adult website, it is found upon by the religious community but there is no law that states you cannot run one.

Comment: @SumnerEvans I feel we can be a bit kinder to freshers. Instead of straight away bashing freshers by down-voting their questions, we can choose to post comments to make then understand the guidelines of the website. I doubt freshers go and read terms and conditions as soon as they land on the website. In fact most of us do not when we are new but we learn gradually. Down-voting a valid answer looked quite outrageous to me.